# iPhone app to log, graph, store and export arbitrary user entered data

Tags: data-visualization, iphone-app, data

Is there an iPhone app to log, graph, store and export arbitrary user entered data? 
Needs to have:

- Create and name a data stream or measurement (e.g. 'number of tomatoes harvested per day from my garden')
- Enter data points (with automated datetime stamps)
- See graphs of the data (as line or bar charts)
- Export the data to csv if required

Lots of apps can do this for specific data (e.g. weight, BMI etc). Is there one for arbitrary data?

Comment: Actually the tracking of such medical and health data points is built into iOS 8 & 9 in a database managed by Apple through their [`HealthKit`](https://developer.apple.com/healthkit/) technology. No special app is needed as you can use the bundled Health app to view and enter data points for any of the dozens of categories of metrics.

Comment: Thanks but can you add new custom measurements to the Health app?

Comment: You can enter fresh data points into the Health app such as "my weight is 202 pounds today". But you cannot define your own categories and metrics. Apple defines those categories and metrics. iOS 9 brings additional ones such as water consumption and reproductive measures such as menstrual cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Pryv](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pryv/id826320447?mt=8) may meet most of your requirements.

## Main features

#### Log what you want

You can log data (numeric or not) and see numeric as graphs. I also used as a diary for one time.

#### Share what you want

You can choose to share some of your Pryv data (let's say your tomatoes harvest) with other users via a URL while keeping other streams private.

#### Automate logging

If you are an [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/), you can integrate it with Pryv and have data automatically recorded (I copy my FitBit weight and tweeted quotes automatically to Pryv).

## What might be missing

I do not know about a CSV export either, but this would probably be complicated due to the wide range of data you can log in Pryv.

## Possible drawback (to be checked)

Please note I never experimented with the iPhone application. I know only the web version and I am not sure you can keep your data only on your phone. I suppose the app is just another client for the web version.